# Calculating and adjusting dates based on exceptions (PHP)

Tags: php

Here are the rules:

- The adding of days is always by **15s (ex. 15, 30, 45, 60, etc.)**
- When the maturity date day falls on the **15th or end of the month
  (ex. 30 or 31 depends on the month, 28 or 29 every February depends
  if leap year)** when **adding days (as mention above)** the date
  should fall **ONLY** to **15th or end of month**.
- When the maturity date day **does not fall every 15th or end of the
  month** just normally add days.
- When the date is **February 14** and **add 15 days** it should return **02/29 if leap year or 02/28 if not leap year**.

Here is my code but, I am getting 1 error and inconsistency.

- Catchable fatal error when the date is **02/29/2020** and add **30 days**.

What can I do to accommodate this rules?

```
function adjustDate($maturitydate, $add) {
    $nodays = '+'.$add.' days';
    $date = new DateTime($maturitydate);
    $matdt = $date->modify($nodays);
    $ismaturitydateendofmonth = check_end_of_month($maturitydate);

    if($date->format('d') == 15) {
        $matdt =  $matdt->format('m/15/Y');
    }
    else if($ismaturitydateendofmonth == '1'){
        $matdt->modify('last day of this month');
    }
    else{
        $matdt =  $matdt->format('m/d/Y');
    }
    
    return $matdt;
}

function check_end_of_month($date){
    //adds 1 day to date
    $Temp = date('m/d/Y',strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));

    //get the month of each date
    $tempmonth = date('m', strtotime($Temp));
    $datemonth = date('m', strtotime($date));
    
    //check if the months are equal
    if($tempmonth != $datemonth){
        return '1';
    }
    else{
        return '0';
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add in a condition for february.

Comment: It would be easier to implement your strategy without using the DateTime object

Comment: Can you show me how? I still having inconsistencies using my code

Comment: _"Catchable fatal error"_ Where? What line of code?

Comment: @kmoser the if part but even if it is working correctly I still have inconsistencies

Comment: You have several "ifs". Which one?

Comment: @kmoser starting if($date->format('d') == 15)

Comment: `adjustDate('02/29/2020', 30)` does not throw any errors. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will fix all the exceptions and inconsistencies.

```
$matdt = $maturitydatefrom;
for ($x = 0; $x < $chknumdif; $x++) {
  $matdt = getNextDuedate($matdt, $maturitydatefrom);
}

function getNextDuedate($prevdate, $maturitydate){
    $maturityday = date('d', strtotime($maturitydate));
    $prevday = date('d', strtotime($prevdate));
    $prevmonth = date('m', strtotime($prevdate));
    $prevyear = date('Y', strtotime($prevdate));
    $prevlastday = date('t', strtotime($prevdate));
    $maturitylastday = date('t', strtotime($maturitydate));
    $isendofmonth = check_end_of_month($maturitydate);

    if($maturityday == $maturitylastday || $maturityday == 15){
        if($prevday == 15){
            $duedate = $prevmonth . '/' . $prevlastday . '/' . $prevyear;
        }
        else{
            $prevdate = date('m/d/Y', strtotime("+1 month", strtotime($prevdate)));
            $duedate = date('m', strtotime($prevdate)) . '/15/' . date('Y', strtotime($prevdate));
        }
    }
    else{
        if($prevday < 15){
            if($prevmonth == '2' && $prevday == '14'){
                $duedate = $prevmonth . '/' . $prevlastday . '/' . $prevyear;
            }
            else{
                $duedate = $prevmonth . '/' . ($prevday + 15) . '/' . $prevyear;
            }
        }
        else if($prevday > 15){
            if($maturityday < 15){
                $prevdate = date('m/d/Y', strtotime("+1 month", strtotime($prevdate)));
                $duedate = date('m', strtotime($prevdate)) . '/' . $maturityday . '/' . date('Y', strtotime($prevdate));
            }
            else{
                $prevdate = date('m/d/Y', strtotime("+1 month", strtotime($prevdate)));
                $duedate = date('m', strtotime($prevdate)) . '/' . ($maturityday - 15) . '/' . date('Y', strtotime($prevdate));
            }
        }
    }

    return $duedate;
}
```